# How do I insert data from table1 to table2?

Tags: mysql, database

Table `table1` has got 500,000 rows. I want insert only 200,000 of them to `table2` from `table1`, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    table2
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
ORDER BY
        id -- or whatever
LIMIT 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT **TOP 200000** * FROM table1 ORDER BY *<primary key>*
```

Comment: I don't believe MySQL supports the `top` syntax, it uses `limit` for that.